# chrome browser on linux messes up with font size in px if screen DPI is changed

Tags: html, css, linux, google-chrome, fonts

On my GNU/Linux box running KDE, I've set the DPI value of X11 by using the command

```
xrandr --fbmm 332x207
```

to 129x129 (as reported by `xdpyinfo`). Google Chrome 46, contrary to Firefox 42, unpleasantly scales up font sizes given in px with e.g.

```
<p style="font-size: 9px;">...</p>
```

I can understand the reasons for doing that – far too much badly designed web pages use font sizes in px where they actually should use em or percentages to be ready for today's multitude of different browsers and screen resolutions.  However, I absolutely *need* correct px values for generating a font waterfall to test a font's rendering at different sizes.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

To answer my own question: the solution is to use Chrome's `--force-device-scale-factor` option.

```
google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1
```